# What can cause mild irritation in my outer ear besides swimming?

Tags: diagnosis, ear, itching, outer-external-ear

I just have really mild itchiness and I noticed it hurt when I tried to scratch my ear. It is nothing severe but I don't want it to become severe. I have not swum recently. I don't know if it matters but I also have type 1 diabetes.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It is difficult to say what might be causing your discomfort without a physical examination, which can be done by your physician in person. They should be able to make a diagnosis and suggest a remedy.